# Open Source Issue Tracking web application with Web Service Support

Tags: open-source, issue-tracking

I'm looking for an Open Source Issue logging and tracking web application that supports web services. I've looked around but I get mostly applications where you have to log on to the application to be able to log an issue.

I'm looking for an application where I would be able to subscribe to some service within my client application and be able to log issues from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Mantis](http://www.mantisbt.org/) will work out for you. The web service connectivity can be provided by making use of the [MantisConnect-Project](http://www.futureware.biz/mantisconnect/).